# Missing results after reducing the visualization size

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I would like to count the same log messages in Kibana. With the `Size` set to 200, it turns out that there are two results that happened twice
[image]

But, if I lower the `Size` to 5, I don't see those two:
[image]

It should show me top 5 rows, ordered by count. I expected something like this:

```
| LogMessage | Count |
|------------|-------|
| xx         | 2     |
| yy         | 2     |
| zz         | 1     |
| qq         | 1     |
| ww         | 1     |
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the little warning about `Analyzed Field`. You should use a keyword field.

With analyzed fields, the analyzer breaks down the original string during indexing into sub-strings to facilitate search use cases (handling things like word boundaries, punctuation, case insensitivity, declination, etc)

A `keyword` field is just a simple string.

What's probably happening is that you have data like

```
| LogMessage | Count |
|------------|-------|
| a          |   1   |
| b          |   1   |
| c x        |   1   |
| d x        |   1   |
```

With an analyzed field, if you have a `terms` agg of size 2 you might (depending on the sort order) get `a` and `b`

With a larger terms agg, the top sub-string will be `x`

This is a simplified example, but I hope it gets the issue across.

The [Terms Aggregation docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#avoid-term-query-text-fields) have a good section about how to avoid/solve this issue.

Comment: But what exactly is `Size`? I thought it is just to limit displayed results, like `TOP`, or `LIMIT` in `SQL`. For example: if you have a list of the 10 richest people in the world, Bezos is first, Musk is second, etc. If you shrink this list to only 1 person, Bezos should be still there. You just limit displayed values. This is why I don't understand why my first result in ordered list change if I modify `Size`. I tried using a field that ends with `.raw`, but it's not helping. I took a look at the link you provided, but it's about elasticsearch, not kibana.